# Помогите разобраться с функцией modify_list

Tags: python, функции

Напишите функцию modify_list(l), которая принимает на вход список целых чисел, удаляет из него все нечётные значения, а чётные нацело делит на два. Функция не должна ничего возвращать, требуется только изменение переданного списка, например:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(modify_list(lst))  # None
print(lst)               # [1, 2, 3]
modify_list(lst)
print(lst)               # [1]

lst = [10, 5, 8, 3]
modify_list(lst)
print(lst)               # [5, 4]
```

Вот что у меня получилось, но это почему то не работает, выдает ошибку: IndexError: list index out of range

```
def modify_list(l):
    ll=[]
    for x in l:
        if x%2==0 and x!=0:
            a=int(x/2)
            ll.append(a)
    b=len(ll)
    del l[b:]
    for y in l:
        l[y]=ll[y]
ls=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(ls)
modify_list(ls)
print(ls)
```

помогите пожалуйста разобраться и понять, что я делаю не так.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: l[y]=ll[y] по моему не работает, чтобы добавить что-либо в массив нужно использовать [].append()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Весь этот кусок:

```
    b=len(ll)
    del l[b:]
    for y in l:
        l[y]=ll[y]
```

Можно заменить на такой:

```
l[:] = ll
```

Он делает тоже самое (копирует новый список в старый), но гораздо короче.

А так то у вас проблема была в том, что вы перебирали не индексы списка, а сами элементы списка. Это чинится так:

```
# for y in l:
for y in range(b):
```

Но, повторюсь, тоже самое можно сделать гораздо короче.